# What causes node to return 'navigator is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation

I am using npm package geolocation but I have also used logic such as `if (navigator.geolocation)` and I keep getting ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

As such?

```
var geo = function(){ //using Mr. Concolato's example
   function geolocation(){
      if(geo.geolocation()){//blah
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coords)
        console.log(coords);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `navigator` there is in browser not in Node.JS.

Comment: Anything I can use to get geolocation then?

Comment: As I understood you use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolocation, and in REadme page there are example how you can use it. In node.js you can get geolocation only if you include it in your app var geolocation = require('geolocation')

Comment: Alexander that is a wrapper around navigator.geolocation as he states and that is what I am getting returned as undefined. Yes, I have included the required.

Comment: @pcproff What happens when you place console.log('test') at the beginning of your if statement instead of after navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coords)? What happens if you use var newCoords = geo.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coords) and then console.log(newCoords)?