# How do I know if my code is running as React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to be able to export a package for all platforms, but I am using some native bindings with a plain JS fallback. Normally I would notice the difference
checking if object `window` or `exports` exist.

How can I achieve this on React Native?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is how to check if code is on web, nodejs, or react-native:

```
if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  // I'm on the web!
}
else if (typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.product === 'ReactNative') {
  // I'm in react-native
}
else {
  // I'm in node js
}
```

Sources:

- [What causes node to return 'navigator is not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573293/what-causes-node-to-return-navigator-is-not-defined)
- [Add way to detect react-native (and platform) without require().](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1331)
- [React Native support is broken](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/39#issuecomment-131415769)

Comment: What about difference between `Node.js` environment and `react-native`.

Comment: Do you have a reference to React in your code? or is it React agnostic?

Comment: It is a 3rd party library I am forking to be used anywhere. It is indeed react agnostic.

Comment: Updated to include node.js

Comment: Had to update as I discovered reacti-native polyfills `process`

Comment: NOTE: In 2022 with React Native 0.67, this does not work very well. I can't suggest an actual solution because we ended up not needing to do this, but just be aware.

Comment: Note that as of October 2022, `navigator.product` is deprecated isn't recommended for use any further.

Comment: What is alternate of navigator.product === 'ReactNative'? @BradByte

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question properly, but what we've been doing so far to address all the platforms and have React Native overrides was to have:

```
-- file.js
-- file.android.js
-- file.ios.js
```

with just a plain

```
require('./file');
```

so that based on the env (Node / React Native) a proper file is loaded transparently.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some answers here mentioning that `navigator.product` is deprecated plus others talking about "file overrides", I've built my [own small helper library (who-am-i-now)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/who-am-i-now), where I am successfully doing exactly that, using file overrides plus trying to require certain dependencies etc.
It has been very helpful for me in recent days, feel free to also use it or just [check the source code](https://github.com/maks-io/who-am-i-now/blob/main/src/whoAmINow.ts) for details on the underlying mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

> crete two files:  one called file.web.js,  and other file.native.js, 
>   and import only the first name segment'./yourdirectories/file'

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

if ( Platform.OS !== 'web' ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: if you're not running in react-native this won't work

Answer (score 0):

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity }

```
from 'react-native';
```

export default function App() {

```
// State variables 

const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = useState('0'); 

const [operator, setOperator] = useState(null); 

const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState(''); 



// Function to handle number inputs 

const handleNumberInput = (num) => { 

    if (displayValue === '0') { 

        setDisplayValue(num.toString()); 

    } else { 

        setDisplayValue(displayValue + num); 

    } 

}; 



// Function to handle operator inputs 

const handleOperatorInput = (operator) => { 

    setOperator(operator); 

    setFirstValue(displayValue); 

    setDisplayValue('0'); 

}; 



// Function to handle equal button press 

const handleEqual = () => { 

    const num1 = parseFloat(firstValue); 

    const num2 = parseFloat(displayValue); 



    if (operator === '+') { 

        setDisplayValue((num1 + num2).toString()); 

    } else if (operator === '-') { 

        setDisplayValue((num1 - num2).toString()); 

    } else if (operator === '*') { 

        setDisplayValue((num1 * num2).toString()); 

    } else if (operator === '/') { 

        setDisplayValue((num1 / num2).toString()); 

    } 



    setOperator(null); 

    setFirstValue(''); 

}; 



// Function to handle clear button press 

const handleClear = () => { 

    setDisplayValue('0'); 

    setOperator(null); 

    setFirstValue(''); 

}; 



return ( 

    <View style={styles.container}> 

        <View style={styles.displayContainer}> 

            <Text style={styles.displayText}> 

                {displayValue} 

            </Text> 

        </View> 

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}> 

            <View style={styles.row}> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(7)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>7</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(8)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>8</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(9)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>9</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={[styles.button, styles.operatorButton]} 

                    onPress={() => handleOperatorInput('/')} 

                > 

                    <Text style={[ 

                        styles.buttonText,  

                        styles.operatorButtonText 

                    ]}> 

                        ÷ 

                    </Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

            </View> 

            <View style={styles.row}> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(4)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>4</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(5)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>5</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(6)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>6</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={[styles.button, styles.operatorButton]} 

                    onPress={() => handleOperatorInput('*')} 

                > 

                    <Text style={[ 

                        styles.buttonText,  

                        styles.operatorButtonText 

                    ]}> 

                        × 

                    </Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

            </View> 

            <View style={styles.row}> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(1)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>1</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(2)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>2</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.button} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(3)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>3</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={[styles.button, styles.operatorButton]} 

                    onPress={() => handleOperatorInput('-')} 

                > 

                    <Text style={[ 

                        styles.buttonText,  

                        styles.operatorButtonText 

                    ]}> 

                        − 

                    </Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

            </View> 

            <View style={styles.row}> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={[styles.button, styles.zeroButton]} 

                    onPress={() => handleNumberInput(0)} 

                > 

                    <Text style={[ 

                        styles.buttonText,  

                        styles.zeroButtonText 

                    ]}> 

                        0 

                    </Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={[styles.button, styles.operatorButton]} 

                    onPress={() => handleOperatorInput('+')} 

                > 

                    <Text style={[ 

                        styles.buttonText,  

                        styles.operatorButtonText 

                    ]}> 

                        + 

                    </Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

                <TouchableOpacity 

                    style={styles.equalButton} 

                    onPress={handleEqual} 

                > 

                    <Text style={styles.equalButtonText}>=</Text> 

                </TouchableOpacity> 

            </View> 

            <TouchableOpacity  

                style={styles.clearButton}  

                onPress={handleClear}> 

                <Text style={styles.clearButtonText}>C</Text> 

            </TouchableOpacity> 

        </View> 

    </View> 

);
```

}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

```
container: { 

    flex: 1, 

    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', 

    alignItems: 'center', 

    justifyContent: 'center', 

}, 

displayContainer: { 

    flex: 2, 

    justifyContent: 'flex-end', 

    alignItems: 'flex-end', 

    padding: 20, 

}, 

displayText: { 

    fontSize: 48, 

    color: '#333', 

}, 

buttonContainer: { 

    flex: 3, 

    width: '80%', 

}, 

row: { 

    flex: 1, 

    flexDirection: 'row', 

    justifyContent: 'space-between', 

    marginBottom: 10, 

}, 

button: { 

    flex: 1, 

    borderRadius: 50, 

    alignItems: 'center', 

    justifyContent: 'center', 

    backgroundColor: '#fff', 

    elevation: 3, 

    margin: 2, 

    padding: 15, 

}, 

buttonText: { 

    fontSize: 34, 

    color: '#333', 

}, 

zeroButton: { 

    flex: 2, 

    paddingLeft: 35, 

    paddingRight: 35, 

}, 

zeroButtonText: { 

    marginLeft: 10, 

}, 

operatorButton: { 

    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', 

}, 

operatorButtonText: { 

    color: '#ff9500', 

}, 

equalButton: { 

    flex: 1, 

    borderRadius: 50, 

    alignItems: 'center', 

    justifyContent: 'center', 

    backgroundColor: '#ff9500', 

    elevation: 3, 

}, 

equalButtonText: { 

    fontSize: 32, 

    color: '#fff', 

}, 

clearButton: { 

    borderRadius: 50, 

    alignItems: 'center', 

    justifyContent: 'center', 

    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', 

    marginTop: 10, 

    elevation: 3, 

    padding: 10, 

}, 

clearButtonText: { 

    fontSize: 24, 

    color: '#333', 

},
```

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).