# Typescript including different files depending on compilation command

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tsc, tsconfig

I used `creat-react-app` to initialize some code which I want to share between native and web. In my `package.json` I have two separate commands for starting for each platform using `react-scripts-ts` and `react-native-scripts-ts`:

*package.json*

```
...,
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "clean": "rimraf artifacts",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run tsc --",
    "start-web": "npm run build && react-scripts-ts start",
    "start-native": "npm run build && react-native-scripts start",
},
...
```

(a detailed description on how to do this can be found here https://medium.com/@yannickdot/write-once-run-anywhere-with-create-react-native-app-and-react-native-web-ad40db63eed0)

This great and I can use `react-native` components on both platforms. The problem I have is when I try to use external packages such as `react-routing`.

I include both `react-router-native` and `react-router-dom` in my `package.json`. I am trying to achieve what is described in this article (https://medium.com/@yannickdot/hi-jared-2650fbb2eda1) but using typescript not JS, giving me:

*routing.native.tsx*

```
export {
  NativeRouter as Router, // Rename
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-native'
```

*routing.web.tsx*

```
export {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

However, contrary as described in the article, when using typescript, it is not automatically recognized which file should be included. I get the simple error:

```
src/App.tsx:10:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './routing'.

10 import Router                        from "./routing";
```

Which makes sense because when I look at the output of the compiler, no module `routing` exists:

```
artifacts
   | App.js
   | routing 
        | routing.native.js
        | routing.web.js
```

**How can I tell the typescript compiler to include all `*.native.tsx` files when running the `start-native` command and all `*.web.tsx` files when running the `start-web` commmand?**

Ideally, this should be possible at compile-time, passing additional parameters into the typescript compiler, which override the `tsconfig.json`. Example:

`tsc --exclude="./**/*.native.tsx"`

I know this can be done with a hacked solution, e.g. by writing a script to copy the entire source, deleting all unwanted files, keeping the correct ones, and compiling that copied source folder, but I want to know if there is a more neat way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you bundling your code with a tool, like Webpack ?

Comment: No - not yet. Is there no way to achieve this without adding another additional tool?

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution without using external tools :

#### 1. Create a function to check the platform running

see [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468022/how-do-i-know-if-my-code-is-running-as-react-native)

```
export default function getPlatform(): string {
    if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
        // I'm on the web!
        return 'web';
    }
    else if (typeof navigator != 'undefined' && navigator.product == 'ReactNative') {
        // I'm in react-native
        return 'native';
    }
    else {
        // I'm in node js
        return 'node';
    }    
}
```

#### 2. Create routing/index.ts

```
import getPlatfrom from '../getPlatform';

const platform = getPlatfrom();
const routing = platform === 'web' ? require('./routing.web') : require('./routing.native');

export const {Router, Switch, Route, Link} = routing;
```

#### 3. Use the routing

```
import { Route } from './routing/index';
```

You may add an interface `IRouting` and some type casting in `routing/index`, so that you don't lose type safety and autocompletion ...

Comment: On native I get the error: `.../routing/index.js:4:15 calls to 'require' expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found 'require(\"routing.\" + platform.toLowerCase())'
`

On web I get the error:
`./node_modules/react-router-native/NativeRouter.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  */
| const NativeRouter = (props) => (
|   <MemoryRouter {...props}/>
| )
|`

Comment: Especially the web error is weird as I know it imports the correct file (which I also checked for the correct contents), namely `web` which imports from `react-router-dom` but it complains about a `react-router-native` class

Comment: I updated part 2. Create routing/index.ts, to avoid having a variable inside require. I think this should solve the first problem

Comment: Thank you, the first problem was fixed - which is why accepted the answer. The second problem persists, but this might even be unrelated to this question

Comment: Try to replace `require('./routing.native')` with `eval('require')('./routing.native')` in `routing/index` and see if it's working for both