# npm module to use both in a react.js project and in a react native project: how to define the different behaviour in the code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

Supposing to work in the index.js of the module, I should define something like

```
if (we are in a react.js project){
   do this;
} else if (we are in react native project){
   do this;
}
```

how can I identify if the module is used in a reactjs project or in react native project?

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: @VictorF yes, I read your reply. I will test it and then I will be able to say if it's the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39473604/9572013) answer. It says that you can do like this:

```js
if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
  // React
}
else if (typeof navigator != 'undefined' && navigator.product == 'ReactNative') {
  // React Native
}
```